# Is Red5 able to record audio from an iPhone or iPad?

Tags: php, android, ios, flash, audio-recording

So what I am trying to do is allow users to record their voice and then play it back on the same page on both desktop and mobile devices.  It doesn't save their voice its just for that page.  I'm pretty sure Red5 is flash so will still allow me to record the users voice (though the browser) on an apple mobile device?